# Unfortunately Application has stopped while launching google maps Activity

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to create an application using google app activity .I have just followed the steps to create a google map application using Google maps activity and not added any extra code. The application gets crashed while launching it.I have given my manifests file, builde.gradle(app) and logcat below.
Here is my Manifest File

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.ranjit.getlocation">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">


        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyDd-cGnR0SwDXXDRQPqnTDpBTQ" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

below is the build.gradle(app) file

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.ranjit.getlocation"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

logcat of the application is below

```
 08-12 10:50:02.947 15439-15439/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   Process: com.example.ranjit.getlocation, PID: 15439
                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.ranjit.getlocation-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.ranjit.getlocation-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib, /system/lib/arm]]
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5029)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4621)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4561)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:139)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1353)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
                                                       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.ranjit.getlocation-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.ranjit.getlocation-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib, /system/lib/arm]]
                                                       at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
                                                       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5014)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4621) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4561) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:139) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1353) 
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257) 
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609) 
                                                       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to include multiDex in your application. In your **manifest**, you have not included the **MulitiDexApplication**.

```
ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path: DexPathList
```

Add this to your dependencies.

```
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
```

In your Gradle add `multiDexEnabled true`.

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 21 
        targetSdkVersion 26
        multiDexEnabled true    // add this line
    }
    ...
}
```

In your manifest add multiDex application class.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapp">
    <application
            android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" >
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Avoid including complete play service (`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'`) library. instead, use particular library you need.

Inclued this **dependency** for map.

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4
```

Comment: @Bhuvnesh Bs I have already added it in build.gradle(app) file

Comment: see the updated answer. you have included complete play services. use the map dependency alone. get it from my updated answer.

Comment: In your manifest, you have not included the MulitiDexApplication.